Dirichlet boundary condition gives trivial solution only
I am trying to find the energy eigenfunctions for the one dimensional particle in a box. I know it can be calculated exactly in Mathematica but numerically I only get the trivial solution. How to find the nontrivial solutions too using NDSolve or NDSolveValue? My attempt:
a = NDEigenvalues[{-Laplacian[psi[x], {x}], DirichletCondition[psi[x]== 0, True]}, psi, {x, 0, 1}, 39];
uval = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x], {x}] == a[[1]]*u[x], u[0] == u[1] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[uval[x], {x, 0., 1.}]


I think you should use NDEigensystem for this sort of thing. It will now give non-trivial solutions for each eigenvalue.  https://i.sstatic.net/jtXi9aoF.png

Can the eigenfunctions be accessed later to perform integration?

Can the eigenfunctions be accessed later to perform integration? Sure. Just do {eigv, eigf} = NDEigensystem[....] then do eigf[[1]] to access the first eigenfunction for example and eigf[[2]] for the second and so on.  Ofcourse, you can do all this using DEigensystem but I assume you want numerical.

@SadmanSakib as per Nasser’s comment in your previous  question, please post the code (and if you think the graphic is helpful:fine). Users are helpful but are unlikely to offer answers without copyable code. It helps everyone.

As requested by @ubpdqn , please show us the code text rather than a screenshot of it. The question will be reopened once it meets the standard of the site.

@Nasser Thank you.

@SadmanSakib I am sorry if you took offence to my suggestion. I appreciate you have your answer via Nasser’s comment and linked graphic. As xzczd comment supports the site expectation is for copyable code even for questions that may be soluble by inspection of the graphic. Good luck.

@ubpdqn No worries. No offense was taken.
